# How to inject an ext. property in spring-boot gradle plugin properties

Tags: spring-boot-gradle-plugin

The spring boot gradle plugin let's us specify:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            version = 'a version'
        }
    }
}
```

The [git-versioner-plugin](https://github.com/passsy/gradle-GitVersioner) can be applied so, the git external properties are set.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to inject an ext. property as a version in the buildInfo task of spring-boot-plugin. The git-versioner gradle plugin defines a few of these, like the $gitVersionName. These aren't resolved when like this:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/passsy/gradle-GitVersioner/master/git-versioner.gradle'

springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            version = $gitVersionName
        }
    }
}
```

The property is set, which is tested by printing it.

What I gather is that properties is a groovy method.. Any gradle expert knows how to tackle this? Thank You.,

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it actually just works when running the spring boot application from gradle opposed to run it in Intellij. The task 'bootBuildInfo' is then executed to populate the build-info.properties file, packaged in the spring-boot jar.